# Parent theme hook is still being called when overwritten

Tags: theming

I have a theme called **hasta**, and created a sub theme to customize certain aspects of it.  One of the things I wanted to do is change the behavior of one of the hooks, **hook_element_info_alter**.  The hasta theme defines this as **hasta_element_info_alter** in template.php.

My sub theme is called **hasta_sub**, and in that template.php I have overwritten this hook as **hasta_sub_element_info_alter**.

I put some debug statements, and I can see that my new hook **hasta_sub_element_info_alter** is being called, but the parent theme hook, **hasta_element_info_alter**, is still being called as well right before this.

Drupal helps says:

> Theme functions are called through theme('[hook]', $var, ...). When a
>   sub-theme overrides a theme function, no other version of that theme
>   function is called.

So according to this only the sub theme version of that hook should be getting called.  Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes **theme functions** when overridden stay overridden in the sub-theme, but this is not a theme function, but rather a hook function used in a theme.

So [hook_element_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7.x) whenever it is implemented will run.

Comment: Thanks I guess I was confused as to what is a theme function and what is not.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong.  Turns out I was just confused.